# apt config file location

Tags: debian, apt

I have my / mounted as read-only (and my /root as well). Every time I start aptitude, it complains that it cannot write to /root/.aptitude/.

Is it possible to tell aptitude to use another directory to store its config files ?
For example /var/tmp/aptitude ?

Answer (score 2):

One option, assuming it follows symlinks:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
mv /root/.aptitude /var/tmp/root-aptitude
ln -s /var/tmp/root-aptitude /root/.aptitude
mount -o remount,ro /
```

Answer (score 1):

If setting up the symbolic link on root is not an option in this case then here is another option for you:

Since aptitude uses $HOME to store its configuration, you can temporary set HOME environment to `export HOME=/var/tmp/aptitude`

Comment: but that would set $HOME for all applications, not just aptitude. Is there not some aptitude-specific option ?

Comment: This will set the $HOME for that shell on anything you run afterwords. I don't see any aptitude-specific option available for this.